# How do I get the value of another column with a foreign key usingEloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

```
Users
    -ID
    -Company
    -Name

Companies
    -ID
    -company_name
```

The Company column is populated with the ID of the company from the Company table so like so

Users

```
----------------------
|ID | Name | Company |
----------------------
| 1 | Bob  | 1       |
| 2 | Mary | 1       |
| 3 | Sue  | 2       |


Comapnies
-------------------
|ID | company_name| 
-------------------
| 1 | Google      |
| 2 | Microsoft   |
```

How do I reference the Name through the foreign key of the company ID?

My User Model

```
public function company() {
        return $this->hasOne('Company');
    }
```

Company Model

```
   public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

If I do a

```
$users = User::find(1);
```

I get the ID of the company but I need to get the name.

I've tried

```
 foreach ($users->company as $company){
        echo $company->company_name;
}
```

And

```
$users->company->company_name;
```

which just results in Trying to get property of non-object

And

```
foreach ($users->company as $company)
    {
        echo $company->pivot->comapny_name;
    }
```

Which just says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are not defined correctly. In your code, you've tried to define the User as the parent, and the Company as the child. However, your tables are setup such that the Company is the parent and the User is the child. Basically, the table that contains the foreign key (users table has foreign key to company) should be on the belongsTo side.

So, instead of user hasOne company and company belongsTo user, it needs to be switched to company hasOne user and user belongsTo company.

In addition to this, your foreign key does not match the naming convention that is used by default for Laravel, so you will need to specify the foreign key in your relationship definitions.

User:

```
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Company', 'Company');
}
```

Company:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'Company');
}
```

Once your relationships are setup correctly, you will be able to do:

```
$user = User::find(1);
var_export($user->company->company_name);
```

Comment: Wow, what a major AH HA! moment! This answer finally helped me wrap my head around the concepts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your relation declaration like this:

```
public function company() {
    return $this->hasOne('Company', 'Company');
}
```

The Laravel [relationships docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one) say this

> Take note that ***Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship
>   based on the model name***. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a
>   user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may
>   pass a second argument to the hasOne method. Furthermore, you may pass
>   a third argument to the method to specify which local column that
>   should be used for the association